# What is a reliable source for reviewing all possible cases when you do/not need to use "articles"? (see example inside)

Tags: articles

Here's an example of the things that confuse me about using articles:

For instance, this site (https://francais.lingolia.com/en/grammar/articles) says, under the title "when to use no article in French," that in French we don't use articles for days of the week.
Yet, when I was doing Duolingo, I was told (if I remember correctly) to use articles for weekdays as a way to indicate what you "usually" do.
For instance, we work on Mondays: Nous travaillons le lundi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is too wide but staying with weekdays, whether a definite, undefinite or no article at all are used depends on the intended meaning:

> *Je l'ai vu lundi.* → I saw him (on) Monday.
> *Je l'ai vu le lundi.* → I saw him on the Monday (of that week) *or* I used to see him on Mondays.
> *Je l'ai vu un lundi.* → I saw him on a Monday.
> *Je le vois lundi.* → I will see him (on) Monday.
> *Je le vois le lundi.* → I see him on Mondays.
> *Je le vois un lundi.* → I will see him on a Monday.

When a weekday can be used as an adverb in English (i.e. can be substituted by "yesterday" or "tomorrow"), we use no article.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For plural weekdays, we would use an article. Anything equivalent to "on monday", we would translate without an article. Comprehensive sources on the specific subject of articles may or may not exist, but such a pointless litany of half-rules and exceptions would be more tedious and complex than simply getting used to each case as you go by, practicing the language. So I would not follow this train of thought if I were you.

Comment: Thank you and sound advice.